# How to redirect a parameter to a subfolder with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

How to redirect from:

`https://example.com/blog/?p=title-of-blog-post`

to:

`https://example.com/blog/title-of-blog-post`

**In the /blog/ folder, I have the following .htaccess file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have tried into the .htaccess of the root, the following code, but it returs 404 Not found:

**.htaccess in /public_html/**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/\?p=([0-9]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . blog/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog/?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Replace `[0-9]` with `[\w-]`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have tried this, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Are there more rules?

Comment: into the /public_html/ folder. I have other rules in the .htaccess also, regarding gzip compression, etc.

Comment: Is there any .htaccess in`blog/` folder?

Comment: Yes. with the following code:

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: @Finder, kindly update your mentioned 2nd htaccess also in your question to make it more clear, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use new rule in `blog/.htaccess` only. Here is suggested code:

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/\?p=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for posting nice answer. Could you please let me know how `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L]` line is working here? I mean no php file is passed to it then to which file query strings are passed. Sorry if it's dummy question cheers 

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: `[\w-]+` will capture `title-of-blog-post` in `$1` and as per the OP's requirements it will rewrite to `index.php?p=title-of-blog-post` inside the `blog/` directory.

Comment: @anubhava, thank you sir. But could you please explain more like why this rule is under only one condition? Where if uri is not a file, because we already have next rule which deals with index.php file one. Will be grateful to you

Comment: Last rule is left over from OP's existing rule and it will be invoked if `[\w-]+` cannot match a URI